# How to launch Maps app and start navigation

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapkit

In my iOS app I have latitude and longitude (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`) of a place the user would like to reach. I want than, when the relative button is pressed, that Maps application is launched and that street navigation to that place is started too. How can I achieve that? My code up to now is:

```
@IBAction func launchMapsApp(sender:UIButton) {
    if (sender == self.navButton) {

        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.currentCoordinates, addressDictionary: nil))

        mapItem.name = ""

        //You could also choose: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking
        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: true]

        mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions as? [String : AnyObject])
    }

}
```

But with this the Maps app is simply launched and I simply see a map of my state (Italy) and nothing more happens. Maybe, because I have run in only in simulator?
Thanks to all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right track: This is my swift 2.0 code:

```
let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = xx.xxxxx
let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = xx.xxxxx
let regiondistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
let regionspan  = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regiondistance, regiondistance)
let options = MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey:NSValue(MKCoordinate:regionspan.center),MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey:NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan:regionspan.span)]

let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
let mapitem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
mapitem.name = "Name you want"
mapitem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
```

I hope my code gives you some insight.

Comment: Can you explain what regiondistance parameter mean? I want navigation route from current location to some lat/lng

Comment: It is the distance you see on the map. So if it is 10000 (m) = 10 km. You will see 5km to the left, right,top and bottom of the point (lat, long).

Answer (score 5):

Your original code looks about right. It's possible, as you said, that the issue was how you were using the simulator. You can set a simulated location via the Debug menu in the simulator (Location -> Custom).

To launch Maps and start navigation to a specific location (as opposed to just opening Maps with a marker at the desired location, as in the other answer), I use this (in Swift 3):

```
let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(destLatitude, destLongitude)
let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
let mapitem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
mapitem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This did the job for me.